# SVG performance - whole numbers vs decimals

Tags: javascript, performance, svg

I read somewhere that javascript is handling whole numbers better than decimal etc.

Since I am working with SVG a lot I thought hmm SVG is about vectors so its coordinates system could be whatever we want.

Now I built this naive performance test here:

https://jsperf.com/svg-whole-numbers-or-not

Question - the test shows 50% faster processing for the case with whole numbers. Can someone explain if avoiding using non-whole numbers actually give any real benefit?

I basically want to know should I (even if the performance win is small) just by default avoid non-whole numbers when I work with SVG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speed difference is largely accounted for by the need to "anti-alias" stroke and fill operations by differentially shading pixels which are adjacent to a path that does not run between adjacent pixels.

While this can occur for horizontal lines, vertical lines and rectangles, it would not generally apply to diagonal lines, curves and arbitrary shapes.

Avoiding non integer values will not benefit general purpose svg drawings. It may speed up a sub class of drawings such as very simple flow diagrams that make use of horizontal and vertical joiners and boxes. Whether the care or editing to use whole number coordinates is worth the time saved is (imho) doubtful.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will read more about this topic. I will potentially test more thoroughly in a test scenario in future and will update this thread.